# How can I commit a duplicate copy with new folder name into SVN using SCToolbarButton on MAC?

Tags: macos, svn

I was trying to copy a folder in SVN with little modification of the files and the folder name itself. I tried to add the new folder, but the a message box which says "the folder is under sub-version control" comes. Which in turn doesn't allow me to commit into SVN.

I tried to change the file modification date of all files in the new folder, but didn't work. Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and I would like to share it here.

Previously there was a file with an extension of .svn in every folder I wanted to commit and that is why the SVN says "It is already under version control". now I remove them successively for each folder and sub-folder using  `ls -ls` just to see whether the file with .svn is there, and `rm -.svn`